# How does `findAll` work in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python

Can someone please explain how `findAll` works in BeautifulSoup?

My doubt is this row: `A = soup.findAll('strong',{'class':'name fn'})`. it looks like find some characters matching certain criteria.

but the original codes of the webpage is like ......`<STRONG class="name fn">iPod nano 16GB</STRONG>`......

how does the `('strong',{'class':'name fn'})` pick it up? thanks.

original Python codes

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

url="http://m.harveynorman.com.au/ipods-audio-music/ipods/ipods"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
A = soup.findAll('strong',{'class':'name fn'})
for B in A:
    print B.renderContents()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs: [Beautifulsoup Docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method%3a%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29)

Beautiful Soup provides many methods that traverse(goes through) the parse tree, gathering `Tags` and `NavigableStrings` that match criteria you specify.

From The basic find method: `findAll(name, attrs, recursive, text, limit, **kwargs)`

The `findAll` method traverses the tree, starting at the given point, and finds all the `Tag` and `NavigableString` objects that match the criteria you give. The signature for the `findall` method is this:

```
findAll(name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, limit=None, **kwargs)
```

The `name` argument can be used to pass in a:

- tag name (e.g. < B >)
- a regular expression
- a list or dictionary
- the value True
- a callable object

The keyword arguments impose restrictions on the attributes of a tag.

It's very useful to search for a tag that has a certain CSS class, but the name of the CSS attribute, `class`, is also a Python reserved word.

You could search by CSS class with `soup.find("tagName", { "class" : "cssClass" })`,like the code you gave) but that's a lot of code for such a common operation. Instead, you can pass a string for `attrs` instead of a dictionary.

The doc has further examples to help you understand.

Comment: so in the webpage code ......<STRONG class="name fn">iPod nano 16GB</STRONG>...... am i right to understand it in this way? : the tag name here is "strong", the class name here is "name fn". i've read the doc, and now understand it. thank you Lotus92, you are very helpful.

Comment: @user1654228 yes that is right..accept the answer if you found it helpful.